# IOS 15.7 does not run on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have XCode 14.0.1 installed which is suppose to address 15.7.  There is still no 15.7 IOS in the simulator, so I'm using an actual connected device running 15.7 for this test.

I have iPad Mini 4 that has my app that works under 15.6.1.  When it's updated to 15.7 it stopped working.  It can not be updated further and will not be available for IOS 16 when it comes out, so its imperative that I get this resolved. I can not downgrade either using 3utools or itunes.  An iPhone that was updated to 15.7 didn't work either, but the  iPhone could be updated to 16 and then the app worked again.

I traced the issue to this line of code:

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename]

filename is a constructed path to a small bitmap file to where it installs during installing the app.

When I run within Xcode, the image is created correctly and I can see the bitmap (if I click on image) on a connected actual iPad mini 4 using IOS 15.6.1 or IOS 16 on a 5th generation simulator device; but when I use a connected actual iPad mini 4 device running IOS 15.7, the result is image=nil, which kicks out as an error.

Does IOS 15.7 handle bitmaps differently?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue according to Apple is that there is a bug in IOS 15.7.  The UIImage can not load bitmaps with depths/precision less than 24bits per pixel.  They recommend using PNG files instead.

It was not clear when they plan on fixing this if ever.

I changed all my bitmaps to PNGs and the app worked flawlessly.